# Fetching nested data in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I've following data in elastic search

```
  {
      "took": 1,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "<index>",
            "_type": "<type>",
            "_id": "75559264",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "request": {
                "parts": [
                  {
                    "lineCode": "GAT",
                    "partId": 0,
                    "reQty": 1,
                    "description": "Serpentine Belt",
                    "partNumber": "K040398",
                    "lineNumber": 1,
                    "brand": "BBSC"
                  },
                  {
                    "lineCode": "GAT",
                    "partId": 0,
                    "reQty": 1,
                    "description": "Timing Belt Kit With Water Pump",
                    "partNumber": "TCKWP312",
                    "lineNumber": 30,
                    "brand": "BBSC"
                  }, <and so on>
                ]
              },
              "response": {
                "parts": [
                  {
                    "lineCode": "AC",
                    "partId": 0,
                    "reQty": 1,
                    "description": "Serpentine Belt",
                    "partNumber": "4K398",
                    "locations": [
                      {
                        "core": 0,
                        "cost": 10,
                        "called": "Store 4",
                        "availQty": 4,
                        "list": 12
                      },
                      {
                        "core": 0,
                        "cost": 10,
                        "called": "Store 5",
                        "availQty": 5,
                        "list": 12
                      }
                    ],
                    "lineNumber": 13,
                    "brand": "BCVC",
                    "status": "Original"
                  },<and so on>
                ]
              },
              "header": {
                "lookup": "EPE",
                "ymme": "2001 HONDA CIVIC 4-1668 1.7L SOHC",
                "transid": "1a97ebd4-514c-43be-be19-2121f2d2b452",
                "created": "2017-12-01T05:37:32",
                "channel": "Pb",
                "errFlg": 0,
                "action": "INQ",
                "id": 75559264
              },
              "documentTimeStamp": "2017-12-01T05:37:47.668+0000"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

***Now I want to fetch the data(corresponding parts ) as per linecode (eg: "GAT").***

I've gone through with [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/nested-query.html) document and executed the following query

```
GET <myindex>/<type>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "request.parts",
            "score_mode": "max", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {"parts.lineCode": "GAT"}
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But here I'm not getting any data instead it is showing the following response.

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

I'm new to the elastic search. so any help for getting data as per my requirement is so much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: Elastic search is of version 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

```
GET your_index/your_index_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "request.parts",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "request.parts.lineCode": "GAT"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This Should work Veswanth !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: No its not prasad!

Comment: @prasad kp We have talked in chat no the problemis that both request and parts are nested

Comment: @Lupanoide okay got it